# Installing Python 2.7 without root

Tags: python, linux

I tried installing Python 2.7 without root on a remote linux machine. I ran the commands

```
./configure prefix=/  
make install DESTDIR=/xxx/yyy/
```

where /xxx/yyy/ is a directory for which I have read-write access.

I ran into a problem at the end. It said:

> building dbm using gdbm INFO: Can't
>   locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
>
> Python build finished, but the
>   necessary bits to build these modules
>   were not found:
>   _tkinter           bsddb185           dl imageop            sunaudiodev To
>   find the necessary bits, look in
>   setup.py in detect_modules() for the
>   module's name.
>
> running build_scripts running
>   install_lib creating /lib/python2.7
>   error: could not create
>   '/lib/python2.7': Permission denied

Did I take the correct steps in installing it without root access? (i.e., my configure and make commands?) Can anyone tell me why it would not install properly?

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 15):

I just install python2.7.5 without admin right. I think the command should be:

```
./configure prefix=/xxx/yyy
make install
```

and then you should add the path /xxx/yyy/bin in .bashrc as:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/songmeixu/python/bin
export PATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PATH
```

Answer (score 10):

You should have prefix=/xxx/yyy.  With prefix=/, it tries to install the libraries to /lib/python2.7, rather than /xxx/yyy/lib/python2.7.

Comment: I did this, but then it installed the bin/share/lib files in /xxx/yyy/xxx/yyy. I ended up renaming the paths, to reflect the directory structure that I wanted (certainly not that redundant path!) and I am hoping that it will cause no path conflicts.

Comment: @ktm5124: Don't supply a `DESTDIR` if you've already configured `prefix`.  In fact, [users shouldn't need to use `DESTDIR` at all](https://gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html).

Answer (score 4):

Don't compile, get the [pre-built binary from ActiveState](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads).

Comment: Why doesn't everyone do this? Is there a catch?

Comment: @GabrielFair - the community license has certain restrictions... see http://www.activestate.com/activepython/license-agreement

Comment: This is simplest! And with `pip`, I installed all my packages I needed.

Comment: It seems they do not supply the latest version. At time of writing, AS supplied 3.4.1 and newest version is 3.4.3

Comment: If you need a standard build, and precompiled binaries are available for your platform, this is a nice solution; but the answer should probably outline when this might not be what you need (i.e. you can't find binaries for your specific platform; or you need a custom build for some reason, such as requising a newer one that the available precompiled binaries).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script that installs Python 2 (which is missing the convenience faculties provided by Python 3 for user installations) and Pip 2 into a user directory so that a standard user can be administrator over its modules etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION="2.7.11"
BUILDDIR=~/"build/python"
INSTALLDIR=~/"python/Python-$VERSION"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}
cd ${BUILDDIR}
if [ ! -f $BUILDDIR/Python-$VERSION.tgz ]
then
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$VERSION/Python-$VERSION.tgz
tar zxfv Python-$VERSION.tgz
fi
find $BUILDDIR -type d | xargs chmod 0755
cd Python-$VERSION


mkdir -p ${INSTALLDIR}
./configure --prefix=${INSTALLDIR}
make && make install

# Append to user PATH or create symbolic link to .local/bin
# [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/python/Python-$VERSION/bin:"* ]] && printf "export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-$VERSION/bin:$PATH\n" >> ~/.bashrc
if [ ! -d ~/.local/bin ]; then mkdir -p ~/.local/bin; fi
ln -s ~/python/Python-"$VERSION"/bin/python ~/.local/bin/

source ~/.bashrc

# Install local pip
cd ..
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | python - --user
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.local/bin:"* ]] && printf "export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH\n" >> ~/.bashrc

# Install modules like this:
# pip install --target="$HOME/.local/lib/python$VERSION/site-packages"

# Add those modules to PYTHONPATH
[[ ":$PYTHONPATH:" != *":$HOME/.local/lib/python$VERSION/site-packages:"* ]] && printf "export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python$VERSION/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH\n" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Caveat: This script is admittedly opinionated in that it will append a few lines to your `~/.bashrc` for the PATH ENV variable. If this is not desired, simply comment the related lines in the script.

---

Case: The service file generator for Airprint service files for use in Avahi does not support Python 3. For the purpose of keeping the system clean, I just install a local version of Python 2 and run `airprint-generate.py` followed by deleting the whole install (saves space on a small Raspberry Pi Zero W).

Comment: The quoting is wrong, but happens to work as long as your home directory path doesn't contain any shell metacharacters. The correct quoting would put `~` outside any double quotes, but then always use double quotes around the variable interpolations. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Also `\`pwd\`` is an expensive and roundabout way of saying `.` if you don't specifically need an absoulte path.

Comment: You might want to put the `printf` statements to update `.bashrc` in a conditional, so as to avoid adding these lines again if you already ran this script before.

Comment: @tripleee probably a good idea to open a chat for all of these comments: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee

Comment: Sorry, not in a place where I can conveniently access chat. If you can wait until Monday, I'll be happy to converse with you about these suggestions.

Comment: The final `source` doesn't do anything useful if this is genuinely a standalone script.  If this is supposed to be sourced by the user, maybe point this out separately (and then the shebang is superfluous and misleading).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building from source manually, I'd suggest letting [linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew) do the build for you. DigitalOcean has a nice [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-linuxbrew-on-a-linux-vps) on installing linuxbrew. Once that's complete, you can just say `brew install python` and have a nicely managed python installation, including pip.

Comment: Note that the linked tutorial assumes sudo acces.

Comment: The linuxbrew readme (https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew - note updated URL) has brief, easy instructions, with no root/sudo required.