# How to install python 2.7 in linux in local directory without admin rights?

Tags: python, linux, permissions, installation

I want to install python 2.7 in local directory in linux but I don't have admin rights. I need help regarding to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Python 2.7 without root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824249/installing-python-2-7-without-root)

Comment: i tried it but its not working for me.please help me regarding to this.thanks.

Comment: Please eleborate more. What have you tried? What isn't working? Do you get an error message, (and if so, what is it?) and at what step do you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `./configure prefix=/x/y` and then `make install`.
Then add the path `/x/y/bin` in `.bashrc` as:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/something/python/bin
export PATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PATH
```

Comment: its showing ./configure command not found.I think i need execution permission on ./configure. right?

Comment: Did you try chmod +x configure  ? If that fails, try /bin/bash ./configure

Comment: Are you sure you are running ./configure from the correct directory? usually configure is in the top directory after you extracted the source of a package.

Comment: Hi Idos,I tired your solution but not working.

Comment: @Hardik what is the error?

Comment: its showing :WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target

Comment: @Hardik this is a foolproof guide: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-March/012903.html

If this doesn't work then you are definitely doing something wrong, it is very easy and elaborate.

Comment: Thank You.. Given link is perfect.I also tried it and its working fine.

Comment: ,I had tried to install module in python.It works.But with matplotlib its not installing can you help me regarding this?